# Как средствами html разделить форму на подформы для передачи вложенных структур через json?

Tags: html, jquery, json, html5, html-form

В общем на форме есть одинаковые имена полей, нужно как-нибудь сделать их вложенными в другие поля, чтобы получилось следующая структура:

```js
{
  'a': {
  'town': 'Moscow',
  'street': 'Prolitarnaya'
  }
  'b': {
    'town': 'NewYork',
    'street': 'WallStreet'
  }
}
```

Сейчас все это идет в перемешку, и получается у ключа `town` сразу несколько значений. Т.к. форма отправляется единожды нужно реализовать именно вложенность, `fieldset` не очень помог в этом.

Comment: А покажите код отправки json средствами html?

Comment: Сударь, вы читать разучились? Как средствами html разделить форму на подформы..
О передаче через html речи не было

Comment: Буквы знакомы, слова узнаю. Не, не разучился. А код отправки json есть?

Comment: @Tachkin не надо было минусовать вопрос в пустую, если не поняли вопрос не значит что его глупо было задавать.

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, не трогал я его, не мой минус. А вопрос я понял, а вот в чем суть работы исключительно через html, если все равно на jquery формирует запрос - не понял.

Comment: @Tachkin В том что после этого у него будет сгруппированный массив в серверной части.

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, я понял зачем объект массива в запросе )) _какой понятливый получаюсь_ Почему ограничился только языком разметки? Почему нельзя было тот же массив сформировать на js, хоть css классами, хоть именами полей, хоть id, нарезать форму на объекты... Уже вопрос поправили, а я все брюзжжу ))

Comment: @Tachkin потому что разметка овер большая, и генерится на сервере, зачем усложнять если все сразу формитированием можно заполнить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял вам нужно просто задать имена полей формы вот так примерно:

```
<input name='a["town"]' value="">
<input name='a["street"]' value="">
<input name='b["town"]' value="">
<input name='b["street"]' value="">
```

Comment: Благодарю, именно это мне и нужно

Comment: @Артур не за что